# Why slider won't stop on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using responsive slider it won't stop on hover, I don't understand why, here is my script to tell it to pause on hover

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function () {
    $(&quot;.rslides&quot;).responsiveSlides({
  timeout: 8000,                  
  pause: true, 
});
  });
</script>
```

Here is live demo to the page where it is implemented http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/04/testing-slider.html

Relevant Markup:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://files.cryoffalcon.com/javascript/responsiveslides.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="rslides">
<li><img width="660" height="400" src="http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img width="660" height="400" src="http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img width="660" height="400" src="http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 660px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
height:400px;
  }

.rslides li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 660px;
height:400px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 660px;
height:400px;
  border: 0;
  }
```

EDIT: Link to the page of the creator of this plugin http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/

Comment: Weird, according to the documentation. it should work. maybe the plugin is wrong?

Comment: Well I think maybe there is a issue in plugin I guess. Otherwise things seem okay to me, or maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function () {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({//use quotes
  timeout: 8000,                  
  pause: true//trailing comma taken out 
});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: still not working, I used it, you can check it in the given link, the script is still not working for hover

Comment: Well if you are talking about files.cryoffalcon.com then its on hostgator and if you are talking about the hookup script which got the timeout and pause thing then that one is on blogger. Why what's wrong?

Comment: im looking into im having trouble finding `<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function () {
    $(&quot;.rslides&quot;).responsiveSlides({
  timeout: 8000,                  
  pause: true, 
});
  });
</script>
`

Comment: cause now it is changed as the one that you are looking for is having a COMMA after the true, which according to scripting is wrong, so i removed it ^^ this is what the above answer talks about

Comment: -_- im the one who did the answer. im asking what file is that script under. there are about 49 script files i dont know which one it in...

Comment: I am sorry I didn't realized its you ^^ well its under this one <script charset='utf-8' src='http://files.cryoffalcon.com/javascript/jquery.lazyload.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that you are using version 1.23 of that plugin and as mentioned in the changelog on GitHub that option was added in version 1.3. Take a look here and download the latest version: https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js